# Use Cell Value as reference for VLOOKUP table array?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I would like to be able to allow a user to change the file being used as a reference in a VLOOKUP. All the files being used will have the same array, just different files paths.

This is how i think it should operate.

1. Click macro button that opens file browser.
2. Allow user to choose file.
3. Paste file path in cell (A1)
4. Convert path to include array.
5. In VLOOKUP formula, reference the cell A1 as the 'table array'.

I am already able to complete up to step 3. Any idea on how to add the defined array and reference the cell in a VLOOKUP?

Comment: Have you looked at `INDIRECT()` ?

Comment: Can you show us the code you use for the first 3 steps?

Answer (score 0):

I would just record doing exactly what you want to do and then replace what you did with a variable that gets assigned, like when you place the path into cell A1. Then just have the macro re-write the appropriate vlookup formula.

You could also make a formula that would show what you want, and then use vba to copy that and paste values. You may then need to find and replace something in the cell(s) to get it to actually convert to a formula.

Example:

```
In A1 Put the path (with workbook name, i.e.C:\Users\username\Desktop\Book3.xlsx )
In B1 ="=VLOOKUP(D1,'"&MID(A5,1,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A5,"\","*",LEN(A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A5,"\","")))))&"["&MID(A5,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A5,"\","*",LEN(A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A5,"\",""))))+1,100)&"]Sheet1'!B$1:C$4,2,FALSE)"
B1 then looks like this =VLOOKUP(D1,'C:\Users\username\Desktop\[Book3.xlsx]Sheet1'!B$1:C$4,2,FALSE)
Copy B1 to C1 and do a find replace of something, like find Users and replace all with Users.
```

This is messy, but I use something like this for a tool that needs to update form 30 different files of different sizes based on 6000 rows of array formulas that update of yet another spreadsheet. It works well for me, but a bit slow for large files.